# Disabling previous versions of an app / sending a notification saying the user needs to upgrade? (iOS)

Tags: ios, database, push-notification, version

- Let's say I release version 1.0 of my app.
- Then say I want to completely change the server/database for version 2.0, however, doing so will break my version 1.0's server communications.

Instead of having users wonder why their version 1.0 app server communications stopped working for them, is there a way to let them know that they need to upgrade? In other words, is there a way to send push notifications to users using the old version of an app to let them know they need to upgrade for it to work?

I know Family Feud with Friends for iOS does this, basically because they add new features that wouldnt apply to the older version. This is another example of why you would want to send push notifications from the developer to the user.

Also, is there some a better way to handle changing up the server/database? (Sorry if thats too general of a question). I feel like breaking the server/database for older versions is bad practice.

This is a hypothetical question, so I'm not actually stuck in this situation, I'm just looking for ways to prevent/handle server/database changes in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically an app communicates with a server via an API, and doesn't connect directly to the database. Since the API returns data and not the database schema, it is generally immune to database schema changes. If the underlying data structure changes, you may need to update the API, but the input and output should not change for a particular API function.

If your API function returns data using an extendible protocol like JSON, then you can easily return additional data to support new functionality, and prior versions of the app can simply ignore the new data.

If you must make a change to an API function that would break the current functionality, then you simply version the function call. `users/get` might be your old call and `users/get2` might be your new call.

In the rare case where you must force users to update (security vulnerability, perhaps), then it is best to have a way to force an update in place ahead of time.

The first thing our app does is sends its version number to the server. The server can respond that an update is required and provide a link to the update.

Push notifications are not a good way to force updates. They are "best effort" only. Not everyone will get a push notification, especially if they've disabled push notifications in your app. Also, why bother someone who maybe has no intention of ever launching your app again? Let the App Store notify them, or wait until they launch your app, and check then, as described above.